# Access to the Frequency attribute of a pd.TimeSeries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, series

How is it possible to access the frequency attribute of a pd.TimeSeries

For example, here I would like to get "H":

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
ts.head()

2011-01-01 00:00:00    0.469112
2011-01-01 01:00:00   -0.282863
2011-01-01 02:00:00   -1.509059
2011-01-01 03:00:00   -1.135632
2011-01-01 04:00:00    1.212112
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

Comment: `ts.index.freq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.freqstr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.freqstr.html):

```
print (ts.index.freqstr)
H
```